# Error in opening zip file in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio

I was developing an app and then i just updated my android studio which failed due to some reasons. I tried updating again but it still failed then i re-installed android studio still the same error occurs. It was working perfectly all right before updation.My log is as below

> 31-03-2017 16:59  Platform and Plugin Updates: The following components
>   are ready to update: Android Emulator, Android Support Repository,
>   Google Repository, Intel x86 Emulator Accelerator (HAXM installer),
>   Android SDK Platform-Tools, Android SDK Tools
>
> 17:01 Gradle sync started
>
> 17:01 Gradle sync failed: Cause: error in opening zip file            Consult
>   IDE log for more details (Help | Show Log)
>
> 17:11 Gradle sync started
>
> 17:11 Gradle sync failed: Cause: error in opening zip file            Consult
>   IDE log for more details (Help | Show Log)
>
> 17:35 FileNotFoundException:
>   C:\Users\Shubham\AppData\Local\Temp\idea.updater.files7337844724625856855\temp5508043076486539057.tmp\lib\gles_angle11\libGLESv2.dll
>   (The process cannot access the file because it is being used by
>   another process)
>
> 18:13 Executing tasks: [clean, :app:generateDebugSources]
>
> 18:13 Gradle build finished with 1 error(s) in 382ms

Answer (score 0):

Delete the **.gradle** directories from both your home directory and from your project's root directory and try building again.

Right click on app select show in explorer to get projects directory.

or you can try deleting **.gradle and build** directories too in project's root directory.